# How does JSON work in my python program?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

So I use the Java Debugger JSON in my python program because a few months ago I was told that this was the best way of opening a text file and making it into a dictionary and also saving the dictionary to a text file. However I am not sure how it works.

Below is how I am using it within my program:

```
with open ("totals.txt", 'r') as f30:
    totaldict = json.load(f30)
```

and

```
with open ("totals.txt", 'w') as f29:
    json.dump(totaldict, f29)
```

I need to explain how it works for my project so could anyone explain for me how exactly json works when loading a text file into dictionary format and when dumping contents into the text file? 
Thanks.

Edit: please don't just post links to other articles as I have tried to look at these and they have offered me not much help as they are not in my context of using JSON for dictionaries and a bit overwhelming as I am only a beginner.

Comment: I don't get the question. What do you mean how it works? It works well. If you are interested in the implementation just get the sources and figure out yourself.

Comment: Like what does it do - I know it works well, but how exactly does it go about doing what it does?

Comment: Do you understand how a dictionary works?

Comment: @user3112327 why did you even decide to use JSON if you don't understand what it is? How is even python related to this question? You could start with checking wikipedia at least on JSON.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is **J** ava **S** cript **O** bject **N** otation. It works in Python like it does anywhere else, by giving you a syntax for describing arbitrary things as objects.

Most JSON is primarily composed of JavaScript arrays, which look like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Or lists of key-value pairs describing an object, which look like this:

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

These can also be nested in either direction:

```
[{"object1": "data1"}, {"object2": "data2"}]
{"object1": ["list", "of", "data"]}
```

Naturally, Python can very easily treat these types as `lists` and `dicts`, which is exactly what the `json` module tries to do.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('[{"object1": "data1"}, {"object2": "data2"}]')
[{'object1': 'data1'}, {'object2': 'data2'}]
>>> json.dumps(_)
'[{"object1": "data1"}, {"object2": "data2"}]'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this: [Python Module of the Week](http://pymotw.com/2/json/)

The json module provides an API similar to pickle for converting in-memory Python objects to a serialized representation known as JavaScript Object Notation (JSON). Unlike pickle, JSON has the benefit of having implementations in many languages (especially JavaScript)

**Encoding and Decoding Simple Data Types**

The encoder understands Python’s native types by default (string, unicode, int, float, list, tuple, dict).

```
import json

data = [ { 'a':'A', 'b':(2, 4), 'c':3.0 } ]
print 'DATA:', repr(data)

data_string = json.dumps(data)
print 'JSON:', data_string
Values are encoded in a manner very similar to Python’s repr() output.

$ python json_simple_types.py

DATA: [{'a': 'A', 'c': 3.0, 'b': (2, 4)}]
JSON: [{"a": "A", "c": 3.0, "b": [2, 4]}]
```

Encoding, then re-decoding may not give exactly the same type of object.

```
import json

data = [ { 'a':'A', 'b':(2, 4), 'c':3.0 } ]
data_string = json.dumps(data)
print 'ENCODED:', data_string

decoded = json.loads(data_string)
print 'DECODED:', decoded

print 'ORIGINAL:', type(data[0]['b'])
print 'DECODED :', type(decoded[0]['b'])
In particular, strings are converted to unicode and tuples become lists.

$ python json_simple_types_decode.py

ENCODED: [{"a": "A", "c": 3.0, "b": [2, 4]}]
DECODED: [{u'a': u'A', u'c': 3.0, u'b': [2, 4]}]
ORIGINAL: <type 'tuple'>
DECODED : <type 'list'>
```

Comment: Please don't answer with just links and no context. What if the link goes away? How will this answer help people later? Besides, the author is already aware of and using the json module.

Comment: Ah, come on. Seriously, ever heard of putting some effort in?

Comment: I believe pointing to right direction not replicating the contains. If some one already explained it and I believe it its perfect explanation then why should replicate ? 

I am not claiming that its my answer, I was just pointing user to right page.